# How would you unify two similar array declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two similar array declarations:

```
allFalseOrTrue: any[] = [{'id': -1, 'name': 'All'}, {'id': 0, 'name': 'No'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Yes'}];
bothFalseOrTrue: any[] = [{'id': -1, 'name': 'Both'}, {'id': 0, 'name': 'No'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Yes'}];
```

Would you recommend to unify the arrays?

I mean I want to have some sort of base thing that I can use to construct my two other and similar arrays to avoid copypaste.
Say if I have something like a source `array` or `enum` and just based on that able to construct my other arrays.

Comment: Can you please give us more informaton or explanation on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: In terms of types it seems like both arrays are `{ id: number; name: string; }[]` or `{ id: number; name: "All" | "Both" | "No" | "Yes" }[]`... not sure what you mean by "unify the arrays" though...

Comment: @Aaron so way if I have thing like  `{ id: number; name: 'All' | 'Both' | 'No' | 'Yes' }[];` how would you construct my other tow arrays based on that?

Comment: Same as you do now, they both satisfy that type. But maybe I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @keysl just updated the question. I want to have some sort source for my arrays to avoid copypaste.

Comment: @Aaron just want to avoid the copypaste. As my two array different only by first item `name` so technically they are `copypasted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use a function to create the array:

```
type Name = "All" | "Both" | "No" | "Yes";

function createOptions(...names: Name[]) {
  return names.map((name, i) => ({ id: i - 1, name }));
}

const all_no_yes = createOptions("All", "No", "Yes");
const both_no_yes = createOptions("Both", "No", "Yes");
```

Or you could create a single array and filter down to the ones you want:

```
const all = [{ id: -1, name: "All" }, { id: -1, name: "Both" }, { id: 0, name: "No" }, { id: 1, name: "Yes" }];

const all_no_yes = all.filter(item => item.name != "Both");
const both_no_yes = all.filter(item => item.name != "All");
```

Also note that using `any[]` is blurring the type, if you allow the type to be inferred (as above with no type annotation) you'll get arrays with items of shape `{ id, name }`, which is better.

Comment: `type Name = "All" | "Both" | "No" | "Yes";` I don't understand this line, what is this called in javascript?

Comment: That's a TypeScript type, not JavaScript, it is a union of string literal types... Basically it restricts a string to one of those values, as opposed to any `string`.